# ChangeListener stops being trigger even though changes continue to happen

Tags: javafx, changelistener

I've run into a situation that seems very strange indeed.

Below is a simple javaFX app that has a TextFlow container contained in a ScollPane. In order to send the ScrollBar to the bottom of the ScrollPane as Text is added to the TextFlow container a DoubleProperty binding is made to the heightProperty to the TextFlow container (which changes after the TextFlow container has rendered after the latest addition of Text), with a ChangeListener added to move the vValue of the ScollPane to vMax (the bottom).

The **Add** button simply tests adding Text to the TextFlow container.

Now the strange part - the ChangeListener works perfectly for the first 9 to 11 Text additions after which it appears heightProperty changes are not being fired through the bind (well, at least the ChangeListener no longer executes). Whether it happens after 9, 10, or 11 times seems to vary with the speed of hitting the **Add** button.

Now the even stranger part - the ChangeListener works perfectly when the app is running in debug (no breakpoints needed)!

I am using Netbeans 8 with JDK1.8.0 on a Windows 8.1 laptop, all x64.

I'm hoping someone can replicate this and give me a clue as to why the ChangeListener is not executing after x Text adds (and why ***it does work in debug mode***).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFlowTest extends Application {

    final GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    final Button addbtn = new Button();
    final Button scrollbtn = new Button();
    final TextFlow textflow = new TextFlow();
    final ScrollPane textflowSP = new ScrollPane();
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Attach a listener to the TextFlow component height property which
    // is set after component has been rendered so we can set scroll bar to
    // bottom.

        DoubleProperty hProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        hProperty.bind(textflow.heightProperty());
        hProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
                System.out.println("In listener " + ++counter + " with height of "
                    + Double.toString((Double)t1));
                textflowSP.setVvalue(textflowSP.getVmax());
            }
        }) ;

    // Create Scroll Pane for TextFlow component
        textflowSP.setPrefHeight(200);
        textflowSP.setPrefWidth(200);
        textflowSP.setFitToHeight(true);
        textflowSP.setFitToWidth(true);
        textflowSP.setContent(textflow);
        grid.add(textflowSP,0,1);

    // Button to add Text to TextFlow component
        addbtn.setText("Add Text");
        addbtn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textflow.getChildren().add(new Text("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n-\n"));
            // Print shows that height property has not changed after adding Text
            // but before rendering.
            System.out.println(Double.toString(textflow.heightProperty().get()));
        });

    // Button to scoll to bottom of Scroll Pane
        scrollbtn.setText("Scroll to Bottom");
        scrollbtn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textflowSP.setVvalue(textflowSP.getVmax());
        });

        VBox btnVB = new VBox();
        btnVB.getChildren().addAll(addbtn,scrollbtn);
        grid.add(btnVB,1,1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 330, 210);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance offered.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs from the `bind` function:

> Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and stopped from being updated.

The binding between hProperty and textflow.heightProperty is done with weak listeners. So nothing keeps the hProperty from beeing garbage collected.

What happens in details:

1. Your program starts with the main function
2. Your program starts JavaFX by calling launch
3. Within the launch function the start-method will be called
4. hProperty will be filled with a new Reference to SimpleDoubleProperty
5. The start-method returns and JavaFX enters the Main-loop. When a function has  returned all local variables of that function will be freed. At this time no hard reference exist for your hProperty. Only a weak reference left within the bindings-list of the heightProperty.
6. hProperty becomes garbage collected
7. The listener which were registered for the binding on textflow.heightProperty recognize the garbage collection action and remove them self from textflow.heightProperty

This is why your binding works until the next GC-cycle.

To prevent this you have to store a reference to your hProperty somewhere outside the local function scope, like in the scope of TextFlowTest. Or just register your listeners directly on the height-property:

```
textflow.heightProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  I solved it by declaring the property to be bound (in this case `DoubleProperty hProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();`) outside of any method so that it is not merely a local variable.